# Good practices - Use of LiquiBase packages

Tags: oracle, liquibase

We change our deploy script to use **liquibase** but now I begin to have to some issues that I would like to have another opinion or maybe know a proper solution for that.

We are using Oracle, and we have a lot of legacy code: packages, functions, procedures, triggers.. (as you can see, a lot of logic in the data base).

We are using the follow structure:

```
.
..
packages
functions
triggers
baseline 
S1301
S1302
S1312
xxx-changelog.xml
```

The **xx-changelog.xml** looks like this:

```
<include file="baseline/xxx-baseline-changelog.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />

<!- Sprint change logs -->
<include file="S1304/xxx-s1304-changelog.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />
<include file="S1308/xxx-s1308-changelog.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
<include file="S1309/xxx-s1309-changelog.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>  
<include file="S1310/xxx-s1310-changelog.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
<include file="S1311/xxx-s1311-changelog.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
```

Because we don't want to copy the file every time in a new folder, we are pointing to the same file, and because we are changing the content, we have to set ***runOnChange*** property, because if we don't do it will fail.

The thing is that we are working in Agile, and every 3 weeks we deliver new code, sometimes we have to change one package in one sprint and we have to change the same package in the next one.

**My situation is:**

1) if we add a new changeSet for each sprint, pointing to the file in packages folder, for example with runOnchange, this will execute all the changeSet that are pointing to these file because the content is diferent, and is runOnchange (is not what i want). But is the only way to know the changes in the sprint, and have track of this.

xxx-s1311-changelog.xml

```
<changeSet id="XXX_SEND_TO_PP_PCK_S1311" author="e-ballo" runOnChange="true">
     <sqlFile path="../packages/XXX_SEND_TO_PP_PCK.pkb" splitStatements="false" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
</changeSet>
```

xxx-s1312-changelog.xml

```
<changeSet id="XXX_SEND_TO_PP_PCK_S1312" author="e-ballo" runOnChange="true">
     <sqlFile path="../packages/XXX_SEND_TO_PP_PCK.pkb" splitStatements="false" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
</changeSet>
```

2) if we create a file only for packages (**packages-changelog.xml**) and we add the changeSet for the package with the property runOnChange, is going to run every time the file change, but you don't have visibility to know when we change it.

Maybe the best solution is to copy the file (the package) in the folder of the sprint, but  I would like to keep the history of the file in the SVN and also have a clear idea of the new changes for sprint in the change log.

**My question:**

So do you know guys if there is some way to disable the hashmap in liquibase ? then I will be able to add it in every sprint and have a track.. and if the id is already in the database should not execute again, am I right ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: In other words there is any way to exclude the  check sum in the changeSet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is old, answering for anyone who comes across it in the future.

No, the checksums are pretty ingrained in how Liquibase works, runOnChange is the correct way to do this. The problem is your should be more granular with your changelogs. Remember: changelogs can include other changelogs.

> if we add a new changeSet for each sprint, pointing to the file in
>   packages folder, for example with runOnchange, this will execute all
>   the changeSet that are pointing to these file because the content is
>   diferent, and is runOnchange (is not what i want). But is the only way
>   to know the changes in the sprint, and have track of this.

Your project structure is good, you just need to take it a step farther. Make the actual changelogs to install the package/function/trigger/etc a part of those directories since they likely will never need to be changed once written anyway:

```
.
├── functions
│   ├── my_function_changelog.xml
│   └── sql
│       └── my_function.sql
├── packages
│   ├── my_package_changelog.xml
│   └── sql
│       └── my_package.sql
└── triggers
    ├── my_trigger_changelog.xml
    └── sql
        └── my_trigger.sql
```

Then when you need to include one in your release you include that static changelog instead of defining a new changeset every time (which, as you have found, confuses Liquibase):

```
<include file="../packages/my_package_changelog.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />
```

Now you have trace-ability with what you did with each sprint without accidentally re-installing packages you didn't want to.

Comment: I don't get it. You have `v002` folder for example. This is a folder for your next version. You are then adding a static `my_function_changelog.xml`. As far as I understand, it will contain all functions you have project wise. But you still don't know which particular function you needed. So you don't exactly specify which functions you want to deploy, right?